# Can I delete this / X datastore from vSphere? vsantraces.index

Tags: vmware-vsphere

I want to delete a datastore (AS lun on QNAP nas) from the vSphere ( in order to free some space for storage)

I use vSphere 5.5

Looking at the datastore, it shows 0 templates and VM's.

[image]

[image]

Browsing the datastore, shows a different story. There are 2 files, I don't know what they are (googling didn't assist)

[image]

[VM Forum](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2334136) suggests that these files are some kind of log files

IS this datastore safe to delete?

What else can/need I check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the datastore is safe to delete. Those files are metadata needed for vSAN, which you're not using.